# using System.DateTime.Now.Ticks for seed value

Tags: c#, seed

I have started a wireless sensor network simulation code but I don't understand the meaning of the `seed` and what is the return value of `System.DateTime.Now.Ticks` in the method below.

```
public void Reset(bool bNewSeed) {
    // this function resets the network so that a new simulation can be run - can either be reset with a new seed, or with the previous seed (for replay.)
    this.iProcessTime = 0;
    this.iPacketsDelivered = 0;
    foreach (WirelessSensor sensor in aSensors) {
        sensor.iResidualEnergy = sensor.iInitialEnergy;
        sensor.aPackets = new ArrayList();
        sensor.iSensorRadius = iSensorRadius;
        sensor.iSensorDelay = 0;
        foreach (WirelessSensorConnection connection in sensor.aConnections) {
            connection.iTransmitting = 0;
            connection.packet = null;
        }
    }
    aRadar = new ArrayList();
    if (bDirectedRouting == true)
        SetRoutingInformation();
    iLastUpdated = iUpdateDelay;
    if (bNewSeed == true)
        this.iSeed = (int) System.DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    r = new Random(iSeed);
}
```

Comment: If you don't seed a pseudo-random number generator, it generates the same sequence of numbers every time starting from its creation. Practical for testing, but for production code you want some unique seed, and the tick count you get from System.DateTime.Now is a reasonable candidate unless you create new random generators in rapid succession.

Comment: @najlaa [*Providing an identical seed value to different Random objects causes each instance to produce identical sequences of random numbers.*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww(v=vs.110).aspx) E.I providing different seed (since `System.DateTime.Now.Ticks` returns different number on each access) will ensure non identical sequence to get from `Random` object

Answer (score 9):

`DateTime.Now.Ticks` returns a `long` which represents the number of ticks in that instance.

By providing a seed value to an instance of `Random` you are specifying the number used to calculate a starting value for the pseudo-random number sequence.

So if you have the 2 instances of `Random` both with the same seed they will generate the same value e.g.:

```
var randomOne = new Random(1);
var randomTwo = new Random(1);

var valOne = randomOne.Next(1, 1000);
var valTwo = randomTwo.Next(1, 1000);

valOne.Equals(valTwo); // True
```

So in order to make a random instance `more random` one can use a value which is less likely to be predictable, in your case the number of ticks on the instance of `DateTime` e.g.

```
var random = new Random((int)DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks);
```

or a much better method is:

```
var random = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
```

Comment: Why is using `Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode()` a better method? Please motivate.

Answer (score 4):

The `Random` class is a [pseudorandom number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator)

> [which] is an algorithm for generating a sequence of numbers whose properties approximate the properties of sequences of random numbers. The PRNG-generated sequence is not truly random, because it is completely determined by a relatively small set of initial values, called the PRNG's seed

If you create the `Random` instance using [the constructor that accepts a seed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww(v=vs.110).aspx) you will always get the same sequence of random numbers. This can be very useful because it allows you to do deterministic simulations of computations that require random numbers.

However, often you want random numbers that are different each time you execute your code. This is why your code uses a seed that depends on the current time. The purpose of the `bNewSeed` variable is to either keep the `Random` instance presumably seeded with a known seed allowing the simulation to be rerun with the same sequence of numbers or create a new `Random` instance with a "random" seed. The result will be a new simulation.

However, you do not have to provide your own "random" seed. If you construct a `Random` instance using the [default constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9(v=vs.110).aspx) the algorithm will be seeded with [`Environment.TickCount`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount(v=vs.110).aspx) which most likely will be different on each execution.

Also, `DateTime.Now` is a relatively expensive operation that has to take the local time zone into account to compute the current local time. This may not matter in your code but in general i highly recommend using `DateTime.UtcNow` and only do any time zone conversion right before it is needed. And in your case you do not care about time zones at all.

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple console app that uses a Random object to print some numbers on console. Create the Random object WITHOUT a seed value. Now start the program 10 times and observe what numbers are being generated ;) 
Then give it a const seed value like 123 and observe again.
Then give it a seed of DateTime.Now.Ticks.

The ticks are something that changes constantly so that you minimize the chance of getting the same sequence of "random" numbers generated again.